# invalidoperationexception In the Begin method of Save The Humans Game

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, exception

I started learning C# using the book Head First C# and i'm doing the game in chapter 1 using WPF project , the thing is  i think i followed everything according to the book but i get a invalidoperationexception in the begin method

here is the code i wrote :

```
     using System;using 
     System.Collections.Generic;
     using System.Linq;
     using System.Text;
     using System.Threading.Tasks;
     using System.Windows;
     using System.Windows.Controls;
     using System.Windows.Data;
     using System.Windows.Documents;
     using System.Windows.Input;
     using System.Windows.Media;
     using System.Windows.Media.Imaging;
     using System.Windows.Navigation;
     using System.Windows.Shapes;
     using System.Windows.Media.Animation;`
     namespace WpfApplication1
      {
/// <summary>
/// Interaction logic for MainWindow.xaml
/// </summary>
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    Random random = new Random();
    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void startButton_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        AddEnemy();

    }

    private void AddEnemy()
    {
        ContentControl enemy = new ContentControl();
        enemy.Template = Resources["EnemyTemplate"] as ControlTemplate;
        AnimateEnemy(enemy,0,Play_Area.ActualWidth-100,"(Canvas.left)");
        AnimateEnemy(enemy, random.Next((int)Play_Area.ActualHeight - 100), random.Next((int)Play_Area.ActualHeight - 100), "(Canvas.Top)");
        Play_Area.Children.Add(enemy);
    }

    private void AnimateEnemy(ContentControl enemy, double from, double to, string propertyToAnimate)
    {
        Storyboard storyboard = new Storyboard () { AutoReverse = true, RepeatBehavior = RepeatBehavior.Forever };
        DoubleAnimation animation = new DoubleAnimation()
        {
            From = from,
            To = to,
            Duration = new Duration(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(random.Next(4, 6))),
        };

        Storyboard.SetTarget(animation, enemy);
        Storyboard.SetTargetProperty(animation, new PropertyPath(propertyToAnimate));
        storyboard.Children.Add(animation);
        storyboard.Begin();
    }
} 
}
```

Here is a picture of my document Outline : [Document Outline](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0N0EE.jpg)

why do i get the exception ? can anyone help me ?

Comment: What does the exception message say?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Property names are case-sensitive. Try to change Canvas.**l**eft to Canvas.**L**eft with an upper-case L:

```
AnimateEnemy(enemy,0,Play_Area.ActualWidth-100,"(Canvas.Left)");
```